# I want to install few libraries on rhel8 distro but not sure how to find which repo or package have them

Tags: rhel, software-installation, ffmpeg, libraries

I want to install few `ffmpeg` libraries like `libavformat,` libavutil`,` libavcodec`,` libswscale`.

I can install it by installing `ffmpeg` package as a whole by [follwing link](https://www.cyberithub.com/simple-easy-steps-to-install-ffmpeg-on-rhel-centos-7-8/). When I install `ffmpeg` it install bunch of other libraries too.

Is there a way to just install what I need or may be install each library separately ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from the manual you provide the libraries will be installed as dependency of `ffmpeg`. If you want to check from where come particular file you can try with command:

```
yum provides **/libavcodec*
```

And to clarify: if you want to install `ffmpeg` you should not avoid install required libraries even if you think you do not need them.